# Implementing AVL tree insertion

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I need to implement AVL tree inserion.

The algorithm can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree.

Following is my full code.

rotateLeft is called twice but if logic is working probably it should be only called once for following input:
2-3(root)-4(right)-5(right)-6(right)

What I should get:
2(BF=0) 3(BF=-1) 4(BF=0) 5(BF=0) 6(BF=0)
3(BF=-1) 2(BF=0) 5(BF=0) 4(BF=0) 6(BF=0)

What I am getting:
2(BF=0) 3(BF=-2) 3(BF=0) 4(BF=-1) 4(BF=0) 5(BF=0) 6(BF=0)
3(BF=-2) 2(BF=0) 4(BF=-1) 3(BF=0) 5(BF=0) 4(BF=0) 6(BF=0)

Note: this is question from hackerrank, which can be found at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/self-balancing-tree

```
/* Class node is defined as :
class Node 
   int val;   //Value
   int ht;      //Height
   Node left;   //Left child
   Node right;   //Right child

*/

static Node insert(Node root,int val)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.val = val;

   insertT(root, val);        

   //inOrder(root);

   return root;
}

static int insertT(Node root,int val){
    Node newNode = new Node();
    Node tempNode = root;
    newNode.val = val;
    int bf = 0;
    int pbf = 0 ;

    if (tempNode.left==null && tempNode.val>val){
        tempNode.left = newNode;
        bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right); 
        return bf;
    }
    if (tempNode.right==null && tempNode.val<val){
        tempNode.right = newNode;
        bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right);
        return bf;
    }

    if (tempNode.left!=null && tempNode.val>val){
       pbf = insertT(tempNode.left, val); 
       bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right);
       if (bf==2) {
           if (pbf==-1){
               tempNode.left = rotateLeft(tempNode.left, tempNode.left.right);
           }
           tempNode = rotateRight(tempNode,tempNode.left);
       }
       bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right);  
       return bf;
    }

    if (tempNode.right!=null && tempNode.val<val){
       pbf = insertT(tempNode.right, val);   
       bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right); 
       if (bf==-2) {
           if (pbf==1){
               tempNode.right = rotateRight(tempNode.right, tempNode.right.left);
           }
           tempNode = rotateLeft(tempNode,tempNode.right);
       }
       bf = setHt(tempNode.left) - setHt(tempNode.right); 
       return bf;
    } 

    return bf;
}

static void inOrder(Node root) {
    if (root.left!=null) inOrder(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.val + ", ");
    if (root.right!=null) inOrder(root.right);
}

static int setHt(Node root) {
    if(root!=null) {
        root.ht = Math.max(setHt(root.left),setHt(root.right)) + 1;
        return root.ht;
    }

    return -1;
}

static Node rotateRight(Node root, Node leftChild) {
    Node tempNode = new Node();
    tempNode.val = root.val;
    tempNode.ht = root.ht;
    leftChild.right = tempNode;
    root = leftChild;
    setHt(root);
    //System.out.println("rr");
    //inOrder(root);
    return root;
}

static Node rotateLeft(Node root, Node rightChild) {
    Node tempNode = new Node();
    tempNode.val = root.val;
    tempNode.ht = root.ht;
    rightChild.left = tempNode;
    root = rightChild;
    setHt(root);
    //System.out.println("rl");
    //inOrder(root);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Very good point. I updated the question to be more visible.